# How to portray to a user the security of an input field?

Tags: website-design, input, security

I was just tasked by my boss to make a certain `SSN` field to appear more secure. We currently are masking the first 5 numbers but he wants a greater feel of security behind the input.

He was thinking a background with lines through it, but left most of the creative work to me. I am wondering:

1. Is it bad UX to place a greater emphasis on the security of a field?
2. Are there any examples I can view that can show such an idea?

Comment: Personally I'd put a * mark and note something like "we don't store/we encrypt/this is only used for verification purposes"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This blog post](http://baymard.com/blog/visually-reinforce-sensitive-fields) is about making credit card fields appear more secure, but I think the same principles can be applied in your situation. Things that help: Adding a padlock graphic, citing your encryption protocol and/or third-party certificate authority (if applicable) and calling out the security of sensitive fields with a different background color:
[image]
<sup>*Image from [baymard.com blog post](http://baymard.com/blog/visually-reinforce-sensitive-fields)*</sup>

And, though it is written with a view towards password entry during signup and login processes, I also think [this post](http://static.ow.ly/photos/original/4loJ5.png) talks a lot of sense about masking, especially unmasking on focus:
[image]
<sup>*Image from [smashingmagazine.com blog post](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/26/password-masking-hurt-signup-form/)*</sup>

I believe the practices above provide a sense of security to users who want or need it without cluttering the page too much. As for myself, I look at things like that little ess in “http**s**://”, site certificates and maybe even a peek at how the form is coded (if I care enough to check, which I usually don't).

Comment: I like this answer a lot! I like the locked icon and the obvious separation from secure/non-secure fields

Comment: Don't unmask the password field when it has focus, if I have someone sitting next to me he will be able to read my password!

Comment: @Vincent That blog also covers the use of a checkbox for unmasking, which I think is best for passwords. I'm recommending the method above for SSN, for which I think it's appropriate. Plenty of webforms offer no masking whatsoever on SSN and I feel the method above would be a nice addition to the visual cues from the other blog given the OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I believe, SSN is one of the most common ways of citizen identification in the US, it would be a good idea not to show it at all, unless explicitly asks for it.

If we are speaking of a website or an application, anything interactive - because I'm not sure whether we are - I personally recommend Microsoft's idea of masking password that they used in their Windows Mobile OS. What they do is they mask (substitute with a bullet or a star) every character in a short time after it's been entered, so the user can seamlessly observe entered input, but without exposing full input value. Also, a checkbox (unchecked, by default) letting user "show full SSN" should be somewhere around the input.

Hopefully this helps,
Greg